# How to sign android application with php?

Tags: php, android, apk, sign

All in is the question : i want to sign a android .apk with php in order to create signed android applications dynamicly !

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There are command-line tools available in Android SDK.
Please, refer to this document http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html
I guess you can try to use that tools on your server.

Comment: impossible...
My process is :
- Create folder with apk files
-Compress this folder to apk

Comment: @RochesterFox if it's impossible, I can't imagine why you ask the question.